# Can two prepositions be used together in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> I was operated on my left eye a month before.

or,

> I was operated on in my left eye a month before.

Are both the sentences grammatical or the second one is wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to say? Even excluding the specific question you have about the prepositions, these aren't clear sentences.

Comment: by "operated on" I mean "had surgery".. further I am just willing to know whether the two sentences are grammatical even though they don't make much sense to you..

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this simplified active clause:

> Somebody operated on me.

In this context, *operated on* means 'performed surgery on'.  To make it passive:

1. We move *somebody* into a *by*-phrase (which can then be deleted).
2. We promote the object of *on* to subject position, leaving behind a **gap**.
3. We add the passive auxiliary *be*.

Our sentence ends up looking like this:

> I was operated on [＿＿] <s>by somebody</s>.

In this sentence, the object of the preposition *on* is now a **gap**, an empty space where its object used to be before it was moved to the beginning of the sentence.  I've written the gap with the special symbol [＿＿], although it would not usually be written down.  It is not possible to fill this gap; in terms of meaning, it's as though *I/me* is still there, following *on*.

Now let's go back to our active example, but this time we'll add in the adjuncts *in my left eye* and *a month before*:

> Somebody operated on me **in my left eye** a month before.

This sentence is fine.  As you can see, *my left eye* is not the object of the preposition *on*.  The object of the preposition *on* is, of course, the pronoun *me*.  Rather, *in my left eye* is a preposition phrase functioning as a locative adjunct.

Now let's make it passive again:

> I was operated on [＿＿] <s>by somebody</s> **in my left eye** a month before.

This sentence is fine as well.  However, without the word *in* it becomes ungrammatical, because *my left eye* can't function as a locative adjunct by itself.  It needs a preposition to do so.

> *I was operated on [＿＿] <s>by somebody</s> **my left eye** a month before.　*(ungrammatical)*

As you can see, *my left eye* can't possibly be the object of *on*.  It needs the preposition *in* to be a grammatical part of this sentence.  That's why your first example is ungrammatical.

---

In this answer:

- The * symbol marks a sentence as ungrammatical.
- The [＿＿] symbol marks a gap left behind by movement during passivization.

Answer (score 0):

First, *operated on* usually stands by itself.

> I was operated on (in the hospital).

where *operated on* refers to the person (I), not the body part. Other information like location can be added.

When referring to the body part, you can say:

> The operation was on my eye (foot, knee, etc.).
>   I had surgery on my eye (foot, knee, etc.).

*in* wouldn't be used unless referring to some activity inside a body part.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is definitely wrong, as concatenating the two phrases "I was operated on / my left eye" doesn't scan correctly.

The second one is better, as the preposition forms a transition between the phrases, but it's still longer than necessary to convey the intended meaning.

Here's a better rephrasing of the whole sentence:

> My left eye was operated on a month ago.

Alternatively:

> I was operated on a month ago, in my left eye.

Comment: I'm sorry but the two are identical except for the use of "in" in the second. How is the second one better?

Comment: We're looking mainly for answers that explain *why* one sentence is better than the other, so people can learn from it and apply that knowledge to other sentences in the future.

Comment: "I was operated on" is a complete clause, and requires something to join it to the clarifying phrase "my left eye".  A preposition works sufficiently well.  But it's better to avoid the duplication of "I" with "my" in the first place, hence my rephrasing.

Comment: I've edited the answer to improve it.